# Filter by model method instead of db column Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I'm trying to build a filter in my rails app that uses url params and returns records based on a method in my model (which returns true or false based on a few different criteria) instead of directly checking the db. I'm having some issues though.

Here's the code in my model

```
def action_required?
    true unless (self.nap_correct? && self.claimed? && self.duplicates == "")
end
```

In my view, I have a link to filter the results using params. Here's the code

```
<%= link_to "All Messages", url_for(:action_required => true) %>
```

And in my controller

```
if params[:action_required].blank?
  @citations = @client.citations.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 50).order("id desc")
else
  @citations = @client.citations.where(:action_required => true).paginate(:page =>[:page], :per_page => 50).order("id desc")
end
```

Right now it's giving me this error

```
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: citations.action_required: SELECT "citations".* FROM "citations" WHERE "citations"."client_id" = ? AND "citations"."action_required" = 't'
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3):

First, you don't need to write `true unless...`, just do

```
def action_required?
  self.nap_correct? && self.claimed? && self.duplicates == ""
end
```

Then convert your complex condition to `scope`:

```
scope :action_required, ->(){
  self.where(nap_correct: true, claimed: true, duplicated: '')
}
```

Then you can use the scope:

```
@citations = @client.citations.action_required.paginate(:page =>[:page], :per_page => 50).order(id: :desc)
```

If your `#nap_correct?` or `claimed?` methods are a complex Ruby methods as well, and aren't just fields in the model, then you need to extract them into SQL as well (e.g. creating `scopes`).

There is an easier way: replacing `where` with `.select(&:action_required)` – that will use Ruby Array method to select records (so selecting is done in Ruby, not in your database – thus it will be slower). And you will have to deal with pagination manually as well, because `paginate` will expect `ActiveRecord::Relation` on which it could run query, not a Ruby Array.

Comment: Alright, I realize I need to create scope. But I need to clarify the objective of what I want to return from my in my query. I need to get any records that meet any of the following criteria: `nap_correct == false`, or `claimed == false`, or `duplicates != ""` (or not empty). I've looked at the active record docs but I'm still having a hard time figuring out how to do a query that returns any records that meet any of the criteria.

Comment: `Model.where("NOT nap_correct OR NOT claimed OR (duplicates != '' AND duplicates != NULL)")`

Comment: If you're using squeel gem though, you could rewrite your query into something like this: `Model.where{ (nap_correct == false) | (claimed == false) | (duplicates != '') }`. I personally love squeel, makes OR conditions a breeze!

Comment: No need to compare boolean value to false :)

Comment: Thanks @Jay-ArPolidario squeel did the job

Comment: @Eli Glad I could help! :)

Comment: @Eli Also, it's noteworthy to use `my{}` inside the squeel `where{}` query block if you're going to pass in variables (this is because where{} is now a block that is not executed immediately). More info here: http://erniemiller.org/2012/06/07/accessing-instance-variables-in-squeel-or-fun-with-bindings-and-instance_eval/